# Nesting two IF statements inside a selection change, both with exit sub and call module

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to combine these 2 codes into 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Range("AL1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.Run "Module2.Sub1"
end sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Intersect(Target, Range("AL2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
      Application.Run "Module2.Sub2"
end sub
```

Doing like this cancels out the second IF statement, but keeps working for the first one

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("AL1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
      Application.Run "Module2.Sub1"
If Intersect(Target, Range("AL2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
      Application.Run "Module2.Sub2"
end sub
```

I found the copde snippet online, I guess I don't need an End If because of the exit sub...But I really need help to get my head around this one. Help?

I'm doing this to be able to have tool tips for the shapes that run my macros.

Comment: Why not use an `OR` : `If Intersect(Target, Range("AL2")) Is Nothing OR Intersect(Target, Range("AL2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `Exit Sub` token. When you select `AL2` the first line returns `Nothing` and exits the sub. Try this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AL1")) Is Nothing Then Application.Run "Module2.Sub1"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AL2")) Is Nothing Then Application.Run "Module2.Sub2"
End Sub
```

*Note, if you select both cells then both subs will run.*

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AL1")) Is Nothing Then Application.Run "Module2.Sub1"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AL2")) Is Nothing Then Application.Run "Module2.Sub2"

End Sub
```

Comment: I beat you to it I'm afraid.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answering and helping me out!